# Полный путь к папке, зная относительный?

Tags: node.js

Если известно что папка upload лежит на 2 уровня выше.
'../../upload'

То как получить полный путь до этой папки?

Например такой?
D:/public/projects/upload

Comment: Взять путь до текущей папки и скомбинировать должным образом.

Comment: `require('path').resolve('../../upload')`

Comment: У меня он показывает 
/home/manking/projects/tro/.meteor/local/build/upload


Хотя сам скрипт откуда вызываю лежит в
/home/manking/projects/tro/server/server.js


Но мне нужна папка upload которая лежит в папке
/home/manking/projects/

Comment: Может `path.join(__dirname, '../../upload');`?